# Adding a new element based on a condition using XSLT at a Specific Location

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I don't know how to accomplish the following.

Below is a part of a document, generated by another program. Via XSLT, I would like to add an extra element at the position based on a condition.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <policies>
        <policy>
            <policyKey>
                <policyNbr>004567</policyNbr>
                <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
                <policyID>54545</policyID>
                <policyFormCd>
                  <code>669</code>
                </policyFormCd>
            </policyKey>
            <transactionSplitTrans>
                <ContractRole>ABC</ContractRole>
                <code>SCBP</code>
                <test>123</test>
            </transactionSplitTrans>
            <transactionSplitTrans>
                <ContractRole>DEF</ContractRole>
                <code>SCBP</code>
                <test>123</test>
            </transactionSplitTrans>
            <Copies>
               <Copy>
                  <Type>Original</Type>
                  <RecipientRole>ABC</RecipientRole>
               </Copy>
               <Copy>
                   <Type>Duplicate</Type>
                   <RecipientRole>XYZ</RecipientRole>
               </Copy>
            </Copies>
        </policy> 
    </policies>
```

I am Trying to compare ContractRole Tag inside transactionSplitTrans with RecipientRole Tag inside Copies Tag.And if the value is matching, I would like to Add a new tag named Indicator with value Y below the ContractRole Tag.And also Type Tag (below the Indicator Tag) from the Copies Tag . Else, Add a new tag Indicator below the ContractRole Tag with value N and also Type Tag (below the Indicator Tag)from the Copies Tag .And then remove Copies Tag from the Output.

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <policies>
        <policy>
        <policyKey>
    <policyNbr>004567</policyNbr>
    <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
    <policyID>54545</policyID>
    <policyFormCd>
    <code>669</code>
    </policyFormCd>
    </policyKey>
    <transactionSplitTrans>
    <ContractRole>ABC</ContractRole>
    <indicator>Y</indicator>  
    <Type>Original</Type>     
    <code>SCBP</code>
    <test>123</test>
    </transactionSplitTrans>
    <transactionSplitTrans>
    <ContractRole>DEF</ContractRole>
    <indicator>N</indicator>
    <Type>Duplicate</Type>
    <code>SCBP</code>
    <test>123</test>
    </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy>
        </policies>
```

My XSLT:

```
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="transactionSplitTrans">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="thisaccess" select="//ContractRole" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="//Copies/Copy[RecipientRole=$thisaccess]">
          <Indicator>Y</Indicator>
          <Type><xsl:value-of select="//Copies/Copy/Type"/></Type>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <Indicator>N</Indicator>
        <Type><xsl:value-of select="//Copies/Copy/Type"/></Type>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean that the first `transactionSplitTrans` node corresponds to the first `Copy` node?

Comment: "*Add a new tag Indicator below the ContractRole Tag with value N and also Type Tag (below the Indicator Tag)from the Copies Tag*" You cannot can take `Type` from `Copies`, because when the `Indicator` is "N", there is no corresponding `Copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="copy" match="Copy" use="RecipientRole" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ContractRole">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="copy" select="key('copy', .)" />
    <indicator>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$copy">Y</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>N</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </indicator>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$copy/Type"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Copies"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<policies>
   <policy>
      <policyKey>
         <policyNbr>004567</policyNbr>
         <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
         <policyID>54545</policyID>
         <policyFormCd>
            <code>669</code>
         </policyFormCd>
      </policyKey>
      <transactionSplitTrans>
         <ContractRole>ABC</ContractRole>
         <indicator>Y</indicator>
         <Type>Original</Type>
         <code>SCBP</code>
         <test>123</test>
      </transactionSplitTrans>
      <transactionSplitTrans>
         <ContractRole>DEF</ContractRole>
         <indicator>N</indicator>
         <code>SCBP</code>
         <test>123</test>
      </transactionSplitTrans>
   </policy>
</policies>
```

**IMPORTANT:** This is different from your expected output: the second `transactionSplitTrans`, where the `ContractRole` is "DEF", does **not** have a `Type` element, because I don't know where it should come from.